# css position sequence issue

Tags: css

In the follwing example http://cssdesk.com/G5q4V I do not understand the following:

In the div called #boxOne, I have first a link and then a div (#formloc) that contains an input and a link. Eventhough the first link ("Appliquer une localisation") is written first in my html, I it is displayed after the div #formloc. I would like to display it before. Hope someone can help. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to float the link as well:

```
#boxOne a {float:left}
```

Comment: Thank you Diodeus. Working nicely :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than floating your #formloc div to the left...

```
#formloc{
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
    padding:5px;
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    border-radius:3px;
}
```

Set its display property to "inline-block", like so:

```
#formloc{
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
    padding:5px;
    width:auto;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius:3px;
}
```

This will position the link before the div by placing your div inline with the link, instead of floating it to the left of everything.

Answer (score 1):

Salut Marc,

The problem is this:

```
#formloc{
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
    padding:5px;
    width:auto;
    float:left;  /* <!--- float */
    border-radius:3px;}
```

Because you're floating this block, it is re-positioning in-front of your link.

Similar to Diodeus' solution except his CSS will cause the A link inside the "#formloc" to float as well, and I don't think that is what you're looking for.

Just add a small change to Diodeus' code as such:

```
#boxOne > a{  /* add child selector (>) to select only first children */
    float:left;
}
```

bon chance! =)